# AML support in iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, applet, ios11

As `Apple` announced `iOS 11.3` has `AML(Advanced Mobile Location)` support. I have googled but examples or documentation not found, I need simple scenario to do : When user `A` calls to `Emergency Number`,  I want to catch this event and send to my server.

I do not know, maybe it is not possible generally.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, did my answer below help you?

Comment: No. As I guess Apple does not have such kind of API at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also been looking for some documentation for this but have not found it. I don´t think you can do anything with this yet. At the moment with `iOS 11.3`, Apple will automatically send your location to emergency services and this is nothing that you can catch. Maybe Apple will release some API´s for this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [Google](https://www.blog.google/topics/google-europe/helping-emergency-services-find-you/)  and  [EENA](http://www.eena.org/pages/aml)  documentation on that.

Apple is copying Google, AML is already running on Europe since 2016. Probably Apple is just implementing the same feature on their phones.
But you need to be a mobile operator or a **PSAP** [Public Safety Answering Point] to receive the location information.